# Using perl instead of grep

Tags: regex, linux, perl, shell, grep

At work we use this construction to, for example, find out the names of all files, changed in SVN since last update and perform an `svn add` command on them:

`svn st | grep '^\?' | perl -pe 's/^\s*\?// | xargs -L 1 svn add'`

And i thought: "i wish i could use Perl one-line-script instead of `grep`".

Is it possible to do and how if so?

**P.S.:** i found there is a `m//` operator in Perl. I think it should be used on ARGV variables (do not know their names in Perl - may it be the `$_` array or just `$1` -like variables?).

Comment: What's wrong with grep? You could use `grep -P` if you need PCRE...

Comment: yeah, i could. but i wish i could use perl =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy:

```
svn st | perl -lne 'print if s/^\s*\?//' | xargs -L 1 svn add
```

Or to do everything in Perl:

```
perl -e '(chomp, s/^\s*\?//) && system "svn", "add", $_ for qx(svn st)'
```

Comment: `expr for list` means "assign the special global variable `$_` in turn to each element of `list`, evaluating `expr` each time."  See `perldoc perlvar` for more information on `$_` and every other special Perl variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use a perl one-liner, but it will still rely on shell commands, unless you can find a module to handle the svn calls. Not sure it will actually increase readability of performance, though.

```
perl -we 'for (qx(svn st)) { if (s/^\s*\?//) { system "svn", "add", $_ } }'
```

In a script version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for (qx(svn st)) {
    if (s/^\s*\?//) {
        system "svn", "add", $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
svn st | perl -ne 's/^\s*\?// && print' | xargs -L 1 svn add
```

Hope it helps ;)